# Transform soap message to objects based on wsdl with rpc

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, axis

i have a WSDL with one service. This service uses rpc. Therefore I use axis 1.2, and I use wsdl2java to obtain java objects(.java). Now, I have the wsdl, the java objects and the message. How  do I transform this message to java objects without exposing the service(some method or something don't involve exposing)?

thanks for any help

Comment: Why do you want to do this without exposing the service?

Comment: Because i am exposing webservices with Cxf in Spring and i need transform this objects to pass them, and i don't wanna expose web service will not have a purpose

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to write your own parser, based on the content of your message. There is a similar question here: [Unmarshalling SOAP Messages to java / or simply parsing SOAP message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402357/unmarshalling-soap-messages-to-java-or-simply-parsing-soap-message)

Comment: i don't wanna do this, i think is the last option

Answer (score 0):

http://bwithers.wordpress.com/2006/07/29/serializing-an-axis-javabean-object-to-xml/

finally  i find solution the keyword was deserialization, in this page at comments is the code for make this without exposing WS